# Twitter Bootstrap with Full-Width feature

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, fullscreen

some time i see web designer use Twitter bootstrap with 100% full-width feature,but i know maximum width in bootstrap is:"1170px ",my question is how to do that?
check this two sample from themeforest:
http://thevectorlab.net/flatlab/
http://demo.themepixels.com/webpage/katniss/dashboard.html
any tip or tricks they use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just leave your content outside of the container class. Something like this would give you 100% page width.

```
<body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">100% width</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: this work for bootstrap 2.3? and do you have article for more Description please?

Comment: @Radian My answer is for TBS3, but for TBS2.3 you can use the "container-fluid" class to wrap your page, and then use the "row-fluid" classes for your data. See here for an [example](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html#fluidGridSystem).